# Keys don't exist in dictionary

Tags: python

I'm learning python, now learning about dictionaries.

I think I understand it quite well, however I need help solving this code:

```py
fib = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}
print(fib.get(4, 0) + fib.get(7, 5))
```

The answer of this is 8. But why? It should be 3 right? Because 7 and 5 dont even exist in the dictionary and it should return None.

Comment: `7` is the key and `5` is the default value in case the key is not in the dict

Comment: Hej `fib.get` the value of key `4` if it does not exist default to `0`. It does exist, says `fib`, the value is `3`. Hej `fib.get` value at key `7`, if does not exist default `5`. It does not exist, says `fib`, here is `5`. `3 + 5 = 8`.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument of `get` is the default value: if the key isn't found, it'll return the second argument instead of `None`. So, `fib.get(7, 5)` will not find 7 and default to 5, leaving you with 3+5 which is 8.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look over here the fib.get(7,7) is providing with the output of 7 as the second argument is considered to be default value it gives out 7 over there just like just above there fib.get(6,6) gives out 6 as an output. so when you provide fib.get(7,5) the second argument comes over there and gives out output adding with the value of first fib.get(4,3) which is 3 and final output of fib.get(4,0) +fib.get(7,5)] will be 8.. image makes you more clear